# Kyle Reese in Terminator 2

Tags: the-terminator-series, terminator-2-judgment-day

In Terminator 2 Judgement Day, Sarah Connor has a dream that Kyle Reese comes to visit her in the hospital to warn her about the future. It's the same Kyle Reese played by Michael Biehn in The Terminator.

Why isn't he listed in the cast for Terminator 2 Judgement Day in the final credits?

I checked IMDb as well and I can't find anything there either.

Comment: It could well be an uncredited appearance. However, I found that some sites do list Biehn in the T2 movie.

Comment: Check this site: https://www.ranker.com/list/full-cast-of-terminator-2-judgment-day-actors-and-actresses/reference. In fact even Wikipedia lists his name in the cast.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As you mentioned in your question, Michael Biehn appeared as Kyle Reese in Sarah's dream. And according to the info [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminator_2:_Judgment_Day#Cast):

> Michael Biehn returned to the series as Kyle Reese, a soldier from 2029, in a short appearance in Sarah's dream. ***Biehn's scene was not featured in the theatrical release of the film***, but it was restored in extended versions of the film.

This could be one reason why his name wasn't in the end credits.

Comment: Indeed, I have probably seen the movie over a dozen times, but it was mostly on an early edition VHS - I've never seen that scene.

Comment: Even on a 20 year old DVD, I've also never seen that scene.

Comment: I don't believe this scene ever made it into the full cut of the film. It has only appeared in director's cuts etc. There are a number of scenes like this, such as where the Terminator attempts to smile, and where Sarah wants to destroy the chip in the terminator early on only for John to display some leadership qualities and stop her from doing so.